Are "don't normally use" and "normally don't use" interchangeable?

(1) We don't normally use a third-person singular pronoun to refer to a
celebrity. If you used kanojo (= she) to
refer to Dua Lipa, you would probably sound unnatural.
(2) We normally don't use a third-person singular pronoun to refer to a
celebrity. If you used kanojo (= she) to
refer to Dua Lipa, you would probably sound unnatural.

Do (1) and (2) have the same meaning?
I guess that (1) and (2) have the same meaning, but I can not be sure because I learned in school that "not often" and "often not" are not interchangeable.

Yes they mean the same. You could also say Normally we don't use... They are the same because it's clear which word normally qualifies in those examples. Often is different because it's a much more flexible word and changing the position can change the word it's qualifying.
